# Cancel active object on canvas

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I am using fabricjs to implement image editor on the undo/redo function, when undoing an action, I set the current object's visible property as false. But if the current object is an active object, its controls will remain even if it has been hidden. How can I cancel current active objects on canvas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***DEMO***

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
var rect = new fabric.Rect({
  width: 100,
  height: 100,
  left: 10,
  top: 10,
  fill: 'yellow',
  active:true
});
canvas.add(rect);
canvas.setActiveObject(rect);

function discard(){
 canvas.discardActiveObject();
 canvas.renderAll();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.js"></script>
<button onclick="discard()">Discard</button>
<canvas id="c" width="600" height="600"></canvas>
```

use [discardActiveObject()](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html#discardActiveObject) to deselect object. Here is [demo](http://fabricjs.com/manage-selection).